# How to set up WooCommere with Virtual on Variable products

Tags: woocommerce

How can I in WooCommerce set all products to virtual?

Apperantly this does not work:

```
function set_virtual(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        //global $product;
        $id=get_the_ID();
        $post=get_post();
        $product=wc_get_product($id);
        $product->set_virtual(true);
        $name=$product->get_name();
        $id=$product.save();
        echo "Product (event): $name ($id) should now be virtual ";
        //But it does not work!!
        

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

I want to use it for setting variable products in WooCommerce, which cannot be set virtual in the user interface. To be used on summer camp holiday bookings, concert bookings etc. where the product has a variable price, the "store" is fixed by the size of the camp/event, but you want virtual setting because no product is shipped. (There is no need for the processing step in WooCommerce - Virtual products skip that step)

Comment: You're asking this on StackOverflow, which is a site about programming. But it seems your question is about configuration an eshop. This means that this question is off-topic; have a look through the other sites on https://stackexchange.com/ to search for a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

The real requirement is not to make the product virtual, but to get through with the ordering process since the product stock is not a physical stock which needs to be shipped, but limited space in the event, that I am selling. I found below solution to the problem at WooCommerce.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automatically-complete-orders/

```
   /**
   * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
  */
   add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
   function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
       if ( ! $order_id ) {
         return;
       }

       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
       $order->update_status( 'completed' );
   }
```

**Please note:**  This solution will set **all your products** to act like virtual products. You may included into the themes functions.php, or into a customized plugin in body